# What does it mean to say "a divides b"

Tags: definition, divisibility, relations, order-theory

I am not a number theorist and I am learning about relations.

I encountered a relation that says

> $a \leq b$ if $a$ divides $b$

Can someone clarify what it means to a number to divide another number?

Does it mean what I think? $a$ divides $b$ if $a | b \in \mathbb{Z}$?

> So given a set $S = \{a, a^2, a^3, \ldots\}$, with relation $a | b \leftrightarrow a \leq b$, does the relation hold
>   going from left to right or right to left? i.e. $a|a^2, a^2|a^3,
> \ldots$

Comment: Let $(G,\circ)$ be a group. We then say that $a\mid b$ (read as "$a$ divides $b$") if, $$\exists c\in G\mid b=a\circ c$$

Comment: A common mistake is to confuse the *statement* $a \mid b$, which may be either true or false but is nonetheless a relationship between two numbers, with the *quotient* $a/b$ (i.e., a number). So "$a/b \in \Bbb Z$" makes sense, and may be true or false. But "$a \mid b \in \Bbb Z$" is not a well-formed statement.

Comment: "a divides b" means  a and b are integers and there is an integer n, such that n x a = b; or, if you prefer $b/a \in \mathbb Z$, or if you prefer "a divides into b evenly with no remainder".  The notation $a | b$ doesn't mean what you think it does.  "|" isn't an operation that give a third value.  $a | b$ is shorthand for the sentence "a divides b".  So it goes left to right $a|a^2$ and $a^k | a^{k+m}$ etc.

Comment: @pjs36 Not that $a | b \iff b/a \in \mathbb Z$.  and not the other way.

Comment: If the terminology is more familiar, "$a$ divides $b$" is the same as "$b$ is divisible by $a$".

Comment: @user170039 In a group, this makes little sense, as in: by definition of group $a$ will always divide $b$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: You are right. However, the comment was written because one of the tags of the OP was [tag:group-theory] (which was removed subsequently).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Given two integers $a$ and $b$, we say $a$ **divides** $b$ if there is an integer $c$ such that $b=ac$.
>   [Source](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~pkirby/mad2104/SlideShow/s5_1.pdf).

This is what $a$ divides $b$ means. The shorthand notation is
$$a|b$$.

In your example, 
$$a|a^2\iff a\leq a^2$$
since by definition there exists $c$ such that $a^2 = ac$, namely $a = c$.

Comment: Yikes, shouldn't it be $b$ divides $a$, since "b divison operator a = b/a = c$

Comment: No, you are reading the definition incorrectly.

Comment: Wait, were you calling the pipe symbol $|$ the division operator? I'm not even sure what that means, but **no** $a\mid b$ is not the same as $a/b$. $a/b$ may not be an integer, like $3/4$, while $a\mid b$ guarantees all intgers $b = ac$, like $4\mid 8$ implies $8 = 4(2)$.

Comment: The pipe symbol "|" and the quotient symbol "/" are completely different things. That's the source of your confusion.  "a|b" is shorthand for "a divides evenly into b with no remainder"  whereas "a/b" is the result you get when you divide b into a.  Different concepts.  Note:  $a | b \iff b/a \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Max: Thank you, I just notice that my book said *$b=ac$, or equivalently, if $\frac{b}{a}$ is an integer*, so that's why my book adds the constraint on $a$?

Comment: @Niing Yes, $\frac{b}{a}$ must be an integer. Hence, $a\neq 0$ for $\frac{b}{a}$. For example, take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174535/does-zero-divide-zero) regarding $0|0$ and why it can make sense.

Answer (score 9):

We say $a$ divides $b$, denoted by $a | b$,  if $b$ is a multiple of $a$ (ie, $b$ is an *integer* multiple of $a$). Equivalently, $a |b$ iff $b=ka$ for some integer $k$.

To remember what "$2$ divides $6$" means, perhaps you can remember the phrase "$2$ divides $6$ into $3$ parts".  Hence, $2 | 6$.

Note that $2 | 0$ because $0$ is an integer multiple of $2$: $0 = k2$ for some integer $k$. Just take $k=0$.