# Does zero divide zero

Tags: divisibility

I wanted to know is zero divisible by zero? I've read that division by zero is not allowed in mathematics, but for instance in Apostol's *Introduction to analytic number theory*, it states that only $0$ divides $0$, and I've seen problems in form $0\mid f(x)$, wanting the possible amounts of $x$ (integer amounts).

This might be similar to some other topics, but they examine the problem in the set of real numbers (analytic sight), but mine is concered with elementary number theory which concerns integers.

Comment: AFAIK, Everything divides 0 except 0.

Comment: In arithmetics, one says that [$b$ divides $a$ if there is $c$ such that $ a = b c$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_(ring_theory)). With this definition, zero divides zero alright.

Comment: Can I find a $k$ such that $k\cdot 0=0$? Yes, easily. So zero divides zero. Can I find a $k$ for any other result? No. So zero divides **only** zero, no other number.

Comment: @Joffan But that k could be anything. So everything divides 0 right ? that is the opposite of what cited in the question.

Comment: @A---B You're focussing on the wrong bit of the equation - the $k$ is only the means to showing that zero divides zero.

Comment: @Joffan  "Can I find a k for any other result?" What is any other result ?

Comment: @A---B any other result of the multiplication, that is $k\cdot 0 = a$ with $a\ne0$

Comment: @Joffan I get it now, I was thinking about wrong side of the equation.

Comment: "Is zero divisible by zero" is a different question from "can we divide zero by zero." They are related questions, but they are not the same question.

Comment: See also [Why would some elementary number theory notes exclude $0\mid 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/666103/242) $\ $

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This depends on your context.

In the context of fields, like the rational numbers or the real numbers, $0$ does not divide anything, since division is given by multiplying by the multiplicative inverse (which exists from the axioms).

However, in the context of the natural numbers we define the divisibility relation as follows: $$n\mid m\iff\exists k:k\cdot n=m.$$

In that case, *every* number divides $0$, including $0$ itself. (Note that $\exists k$ is bounded to the natural numbers here!)

Answer (score 5):

If you're asking if zero is divisible by zero and you agree on the definition of divisibility to be

> If $x$ and $y$ are two integers then $x$ is said to be divisible by $y$ if there *exists* an integer value $p$ such that $x = py$

Then zero *is certainly divisible by zero as every integer follows that definition.* If your notion of divisibility actually means to be able to divide those two and get some definite value then **it is not divisible** But according to what I think it is.